# How to do BayesianMinimization in 2D?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, probability-or-statistics, machine-learning

Studying a new experimental [BayesianMinimization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BayesianMinimization.html) command in 14.0 and following an example from the documentation

```
bo = BayesianMinimization[(# - 2)^2 + 1 &, Interval[{0, 4}]]
```

, I try

```
BayesianMinimization[Sin[#1] + Cos[#2] &, {Interval[{-3, 3}], Interval[{-3, 3}]}]
```

and

```
BayesianMinimization[Sin[#1] + Cos[#2] &, Rectangle[{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}]]
```

with the same result

> BayesianMinimization::bdconfgenerator: The configurations are not valid.

That place in the documentation

> Configurations can be of any form accepted by Predict (single data element, list of data elements, association of data elements, etc.) and of any type accepted by Predict (numerical, textual, sounds, images, etc.).

is not clear to me. So is it possible to do Bayesian optimization with Mathematica in two dimensions?

Addition. I'd like to add that `f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := Sin[x] + Cos[y]; reg = Rectangle[{-3, -3}, {3, 3}]; BayesianMinimization[f, reg]` up to another example from the documentation performs an error "BayesianMinimization::bdfnconfig: The function should be real valued."

Comment: `BayesianMinimization[Sin[#[[1]]] + Cos[#[[2]]] &, RandomReal[{-3, 3}, 2] &]` seems to work, but I'm not sure why it's so fussy.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit: Thank you, it does  work. However, how about more complicated regions in 2D?

Comment: Use `Rectangle[{-3, -3}, {3, 3}]`.

Comment: @Syed: I mean something like `ImplicitRegion[y<=Sin[x]+x&&y>=x^2-4,{x,y}]`.

Comment: @user64494 Maye something like `BayesianMinimization[Sin[#[[1]]] + Cos[#[[2]]] &, RandomPoint[Rectangle[{-3, -3}, {3, 3}]] & ]`. But with a more complicated region than that.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit: `BayesianMinimization[Sin[#[[1]]] + Cos[#[[2]]] &, 
 RandomPoint[
   ImplicitRegion[y <= Sin[x] + x && y >= x^2 - 4, {x, y}]] &]` works though very slowly (approximately one hour). Can you kindly present your fussy workaround as an answer? TIA.

Comment: Looks like `RandomPoint[ImplicitRegion[...]]` is very slow. Try using `DiscretizeRegion` on the `ImplicitRegion` first to make `RandomPoint` much faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following works:

```
BayesianMinimization[Sin[#[[1]]] + Cos[#[[2]]] &, Rectangle[{-3, -3}, {3, 3}]]
```

or

```
BayesianMinimization[Sin[#[[1]]] + Cos[#[[2]]] &, RandomPoint[Rectangle[{-3, -3}, {3, 3}]]&]
```

If you want to use more complicated regions, it's recommended to use `DiscretizeRegion` to create something that can be sampled quickly by `RandomPoint`.

Comment: +1. Many thanks from me to you. I'll be waiting for other answers  some time .

Comment: Even `BayesianMinimization[Sin[#[[1]]] + Cos[#[[2]]] &, 
 ImplicitRegion[y <= Sin[x] + x && y >= x^2 - 4, {x, y}]]` works.